# Cambiar diseño en responsive bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

Hola estoy intentando hacer una imagen de producto con texto de descripción inferior para la versión normal y en responsive que cambie la alineación de la imagen a la izquierda, ademas agregar un icono en la parte derecha, dejo unas imágenes de referencia, gracias.

[image: Version responsive]
  [image: version full]

```
     <div class="productos">


       <div class="container">
          <div class="row form-group product-chooser">

              <li class="isotope-item"> 

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                   <div class="product-chooser-item selected">

                     <a href="#">
                   <img src="images/imagen1.png" class="img-rounded col-xs-4 col-sm- 
                 4 col-md-12 col-lg-12" alt="Mobile and Desktop">
                      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                       <span class="title">Categoría 1</span>
                       <span class="description">Descripción 1</span>

                    </div>

                   <div class="clear"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
             </div>

           </li>
         </div>                     
       </div>"
```

El código CSS sería este:

```
    div.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

div.product-chooser{

}

    div.product-chooser.disabled div.product-chooser-item
    {
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
        cursor: default;
    }

    div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item{
        padding: 11px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        border-left: 2px solid #efefef;
        border-right: 2px solid #efefef;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #efefef;
        border-top: 2px solid #efefef;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }



        div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item img{
            padding: 0;
        }

        div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item span.title{
            display: block;
            margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item span.description{
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item input{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            visibility:hidden;
        }


        ul.isotope-item {
            list-style-type: none;}

        li.isotope-item {
            list-style-type: none;}

.vcenter {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
}


         productos {
  background-color: lightblue;
}   


   .fa.fa-chevron-right {
         float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
           display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #54c0ea;
     }



   .fa.fa-chevron-circle-right {
         float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
           display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #54c0ea;
     }


    .fa.fa-user {
         float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
           display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #54c0ea;
     }







@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  div.product-chooser div.product-chooser-item {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #bbb8b8;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }


.fa.fa-chevron-right {
         float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
           display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: bottom;
     }

.fa.fa-chevron-circle-right {
         float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
           display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: bottom;
     }


.fa.fa-user {
         float: right;
         margin-right: .5em;
         padding-top: .3em;
          line-height:3em;
           display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #54c0ea;
     }





}
```

He colocado el código y la capa de estilos hasta el avance, me faltaría colocar el icono flotante en la parte derecha central, y mantener el texto y descripción en la parte inferior de la imagen para la versión responsive, también quisiera agregar un cambio de color al texto e icono cuando se selecciona.

Comment: Cuál es tu código y qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola Jheyman gracias por responder, adjunte el código, voy a agregar también el css, gracias.